# Rails console, points at encoding without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting this message whenever I start the rails console. It isnt effecting anything but i wish I could get rid of it

```
From: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0@global/bundler/gems/mongoid_optimistic_locking-f9a685139364/mongoid_optimistic_locking.gemspec @ line 1 :

 => 1: # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
    2: $:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
    3: require "mongoid/optimistic_locking/version"
    4:
    5: Gem::Specification.new do |s|
    6:   s.name        = "mongoid_optimistic_locking"
[4] pry(main)>
```

and that is all there is to it before the propmt. If anybody has any clues as to why this is happening I would be greatful.

Comment: What compatibility version are you running under JRuby - 1.8 or 1.9?

Comment: JRuby 1.9, 1.7.0 defaults to 1.9